# $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 -9 \leq 0 \land x^2 - 4 > 0\}$ and $ B = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 2 < x \leq 3\}$ Prove $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am struggling with the following question. The logic is fairly simple, I'm suppose to find an element in A s.t it satisfies the condition and show that the element doesn't live in B. However, aren't they the exact same thing? For A, x can either be bigger than 2 or less than or equal to 3. It can also be that x is bigger than negative 2 but less than or equal to negative 3. This can't be. But then A = B are same thing...I know this can't be the case because they also ask me to prove B is a proper subset A. Thank you

Comment: Hint: $$\color{red}{\bf -3}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $x$ such that $x \in [-3, -2[$.

Answer (score 0):

A has some elements that are less than zero......

Answer (score 0):

$A$ also contains $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: 2<-x\leq 3\}$.